# Algorithm for bitwise fiddling

Tags: algorithm, bitwise-operators, bit-manipulation

If I have a 32-bit binary number and I want to replace the lower 16-bit of the binary number with a 16-bit number that I have and keep the upper 16-bit of that number to produce a new binary number.. how can I do this using simple bitwise operator?

For example the 32-bit binary number is:

```
1010 0000 1011 1111 0100 1000 1010 1001
```

and the lower 16-bit I have is:

```
                    0000 0000 0000 0001
```

so the result is:

```
1010 0000 1011 1111 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

how can I do this?

Comment: I want to do this in a single step

Comment: You can't do this with 1 operator. You need at least 2, and with sign extension involved, 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do this in two steps:

- Mask out the bits that you want to replace (AND it with 0s)
- Fill in the replacements (OR it with the new bits)

So in your case,

```
i32 number;
i32 mask_lower_16 = FFFF0000;
i16 newValue;

number = (number AND mask_lower_16) OR newValue;
```

In actual programming language implementation, you may also need to address the issue of sign extension on the 16-bit value. In Java, for example, you have to mask the upper 16 bits of the `short` like this:

```
    short v = (short) 0xF00D;
    int number = 0x12345678;
    number = (number & 0xFFFF0000) | (v & 0x0000FFFF);
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(number)); // "1234f00d"
```

Comment: If the OP is a newbie, please note the difference between logical AND (&&) and bitwise AND (&)

Comment: Done. Also addressed sign extension issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
(original32BitNumber & 0xFFFF0000) | 16bitNumber
```

Comment: second operation should be OR

Comment: Thanks! I must have done this millions of times and still managed to type the wrong thing!

Comment: Depending on language, sign extension on the 16bitNumber is an issue.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Yes, it should really be: `(original32BitNumber & 0xFFFF0000) | (16bitNumber & 0x0000FFFF)`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I could tell you the answer. But perhaps this is homework. So I won't.

Consider that you have a few options:

```
| // bitwise OR
^ // bitwise XOR
& // bitwise AND
```

Maybe draw up a little table and decide which one will give you the right result (when you operate on the right section of your larger binary number).

Answer (score 1):

use & to mask off the low bits and then | to merge the 16 bit value with the 32 bit value

```
 uint  a = 0xa0bf68a9
 short b = 1

 uint  result = (a & 0xFFFF0000) | b;
```